# Android - VideoView ignore LayoutParams in HDMI mode

Tags: android, android-videoview, layoutparams

Here is part of my code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.board);
RelativeLayout lView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutMain); 
VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
mVideoView.start();
mVideoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
lView.addView(mVideoView);
```

When I launch APP on Tablet only It works fine. I have Video playing in left top corner and scaled to 30x30.

But when I connect Tablet via HDMI to my TV and launch APP I have only 30x30 rectangle in left top part of screen. Video is plaing outside this rectangle at center of screen size: 500x400 or smth like this.

I have tried also make xml layout with VideoView inside setting all parameters and always in HDMI mode VideoView ignore all settings and play movie at center of screen.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have native HDMI support. Your problem, therefore, lies with whatever manufacturer made whatever device you are testing on.

Comment: ehhh thats no good I bought 10x tablet with Android 2.3 :P With TV connected via HDMI all works fine only Video play in wrong place :/